# What do "instrumental motivation" and "integrative motivation" exactly mean?

Tags: meaning

The following sentence came up to me in [this page.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/example/english/instrumental-motivation)

> 1. Students with integrative or instrumental motivation (particularly integrative) were less likely to experience severe attrition.

What do "instrumental motivation" and "integrative motivation" exactly mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the explanation (in the context of employees of a company) [on customerservicemanager.com](https://www.customerservicemanager.com/the-difference-between-instrumental-and-integrative-motivation/):

- **Instrumental** motivation is a person's desire to meet a goal.
- **Integrative** motivation is a person's desire to be part of a community.

For example, suppose that you're a high school student taking a Spanish class.

- If you're taking it because it fulfills an admission requirement for a university that you'd like to go to, that's instrumental motivation.
- If you're taking it because you want to communicate with your best friend's grandparents who are immigrants from South America, that's integrative motivation.

Answer (score -1):

`"instrumental"`  **compelling, deciding, decisive, essential, imperative, momentous,**
 `"integrative"`  **product of time and effort**